# How to distinguish between BLANK and 0 in a PowerBI Measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables like this:

PM_History2

```
Serial#    Good
A          TRUE
B          FALSE
A          TRUE
B          FALSE
C          TRUE
A          FALSE
C          TRUE
```

CONTRACTS

```
Serial#   Enrollment#
A         1
B         2
C         3
D         4
```

I have a measure that calculates the number of Good for TRUE:

```
Count of Good for True = 
CALCULATE(COUNTA('PM_History2'[Good]), 'PM_History2'[Good] IN { TRUE })
```

I then have a measure that calculates the percentage of TRUEs for Good.

```
PM Score = 'PM_History2'[Count of Good for True]/COUNTROWS(PM_History2)
```

When I create a table visualization to show all the Serial# and their PM Score I get this:

```
Serial#   PM Score
A         .67
B
C         1.00
D
```

What can I do to get what should be a zero to come in as 0 and what should be blank to be blank. Like this:

```
Serial#   PM Score
A         .67
B         0
C         1.00
D
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PM Score = DIVIDE ( [Count of Good for True] + 0, COUNTROWS ( PM_History2 ) )
```

Adding `+ 0` makes the *numerator* nonblank but the DIVIDE function still returns a blank when the *denominator* is blank, thus distinguishing the results for B and D.